# C Programming, if getchar with _Bool

Tags: c, boolean

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
_Bool = b1;
printf("1 = Wahr, 0 = Unwahr\n");
b1 = getchar ();
if(putchar(b1) = 1) {
   printf("b1=1 =>wahr\n");
}
else {
   printf("b1= =>unwahr\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

The error I get

```
10  16  C:\Netzwerk\owncloud\Visualisierung\TAG3\3.5 log. Datentyp\bool_leer.c  [Error] lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

Comment: `if(putchar(b1) = 1) {}` --> `if(putchar(b1) == 1) {}`

Comment: `_Bool = b1;` Does this even compile?

Comment: `1` isn't the same as `'1'`. Same for 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main(void) 
{
   _Bool b1 /* = 1 or 0 */;
   printf("1 = Wahr, 0 = Unwahr\n");
   b1 = getchar();
   if (putchar(b1) == 1) {
       printf("b1=1 =>wahr\n");
   }
   else {
    printf("b1= =>unwahr\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Two problems here:

- change `_Bool = b1` with `_Bool b1`;
- change `if(putchar(b1) = 1)` with `if(putchar(b1) == 1)` or with `if(b1)` as Bathsheba pointed out.

Comment: by output it gives me only the first printf doesnt matter if I write 0 or 9 or else. it gives me always true also as it 1

Comment: @eXme: Did you read the documentation to the functions the code is using?

Comment: Im kinda new to the C. Yes that is the way I understood how it works, but probably went something wrong as I see..

Comment: Can you try to explain what are you triyng to achieve with this code? Why are you using putchar() in this way?

Comment: I tho that putchar() is the output for the getchar() funktion. now I understand it can be also without putchar(). I need it to get first if when it is 1 in b1 variable and other results as 2nd printf

Answer (score 0):

Simple typos:

1 You need `_Bool b1;` rather than `_Bool = b1;`

2 You need `if(putchar(b1) == 1)` rather than `if(putchar(b1) = 1)`. You are attempting to *assign* 1 to `putchar(b1)` and that's not possible in C, hence the compiler error.

Your use of `putchar(b1)` in the conditional is also questionable. Did you mean, more simply

```
if (b1){
```

as `putchar` returns the number of characters written to the output stream, which will be always non-zero in your case?

Comment: ive got another error after == 7 7 C:\Netzwerk\owncloud\Visualisierung\TAG3\3.5 log. Datentyp\bool_leer.c [Error] expected identifier or '(' before '=' token

Comment: `_Bool b1;`, not `_Bool = b1;`.

Comment: Ok. I've fixed all the errors. This question is on the borderline of being suitable for this site; but it was well written.

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
_Bool b1;
printf("1 = Wahr, 0 = Unwahr\n");
b1 = getchar ();
if(putchar(b1) == 1) {
   printf("- b1=1 =>wahr\n");
}
else {
   printf("- b1=0 =>unwahr\n");
}
return 0;
}` it works but i get same results doesnt matter if its 1 or 0

Comment: eXme, added that too.